# What are the benchmarks of Javascript templating frameworks?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, mustache, templating, handlebars.js

I am trying to make an informed decision about which Javascript templating framework to use. There are so many choice, from Mustache, Handlebar, Hogan, jQuery, and Closure templates. I already have some basic rules of comparison, like filesize, maturity (how do I measure that?!), community support, and rendering speed (how do I measure that?)

In short, I am collecting ideas to understand what else is there that would make for a good basis of comparison between these options. What are your thoughts? Please share them with me.

Thank you!

Comment: Do this: Try the most popular one. Does it meet your requirements? If yes, stick with it. If no, try the second most popular, etc. (Most popular currently is Mustache/Handlebars. I use Handlebars.)

Comment: It's not my decision to make. I need to present the ups and downs to my team. Our most important requirement is performance and speed, and I am trying to figure out what that entails.

Comment: Check out this comparison by LinkedIn: http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, a performance comparison on jsPerf:

http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/365

It compares a dozen of template-engines. Notice that this thing is in revision 365 (it has been updated that many times), which means that - as a comparison - it is quite mature.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Distal http://code.google.com/p/distal

For rendering speed you'll have to split by browser version.

You could also measure popularity.